# Variable Axes on a Single Plot in R

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, plotly, axis

I'm trying to use plotly to generate a plot with 2 dropdown buttons (one for x-axis, one for y-axis) that will allow me to change the data, scale, label, etc on the associated axis, thereby creating a scatterplot that can compare any 2 columns of data on either axis.  I understand how to make the dropdown buttons:

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y= ~y1) %>%
 layout(
 xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
 yaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
 updatemenus = list(
   list(
     y = 1.1,    # This is the location of the vertical axis button
     x= 0.5,
     buttons = list(
       list(method = "update",
          args = list(list("visible", list(T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F)),
          label = colnames(df)[1]),
       list(method = "update",
          args = list(list("visible", list(T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F)),
          label = colnames(df)[1]), # etc
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible and how would I go about updating the data that is sent to the plot?

Comment: I get 91 hits on an SO search for questions or answers with these terms: "shiny plotly change variables". (I suspect I would find even more with a google search.) I'm worried that you have not made an adequate to find an earlier solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have been working at this for roughly the last 3 hours and have searched help topics and StackOverflow extensively.  I only resort to posting a question after I'm exhausted from my own efforts.  I'm looking over the results from a google search on "plotly change variables" now.  Hopefully it answers my question, in which case I'll credit you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I've figured out the syntax to change the data on a particular axis using dropdown buttons by translating this [post](https://community.plot.ly/t/dropdown-with-multiple-attribute-changes/2005) from Python into R. The code looks like this:

```
p <- plot_ly(df, x= df[,1], y= df[,2],
             mode= "markers", type= "scatter", 
             color= ~df[,3],) %>%
layout(
updatemenus = list(
  list(
    x= 0.46, y = 1.1,
    yanchor= "top",
    buttons = list(
      list(args = list(list(y= list(df[,1]))),
           label = colname(df[,1]), method = "restyle"),
      list(args = list(list(y= list(df[,2]))),
           label = colname(df[,2]), method = "restyle"),
    )
   ),
   list(
     x= 1.1, y = 1.1,
     yanchor= "top",
     buttons = list(
       list(args = list(list(x= list(df[,1]))),
            label = colname(df[,1]), method = "restyle"),
       list(args = list(list(x= list(df[,2]))),
            label = colname(df[,2]), method = "restyle"),
     )
    )
  )
)

annot <- list(list(text = "Vertical<br>Axis", x=-0.1, y= 1.1, xref='paper', 
                   yref='paper', showarrow=FALSE),
              list(text = "Horizontal<br>Axis", x= 0.57, y= 1.1, 
                   xref='paper', yref='paper', showarrow=FALSE))

p <- p %>%layout(
  annotations = annot)
```

This code works, but 2 new issues arise:
1) How can I change the data AND change the axis label?
2) How can I color code the plot by df[,3] every time an axis changes?